# Can we fire database query while flagging the node?

Tags: 7

Can we fire  database query on flagging the flag(**pick_this_bid**)
I want to update the database table column in which boolen value is saved true and false.

By default it shows **true** status in database but when someone flagged(**pick_this_bid**) the  status  should change to false in the database.

I want something like this on clicking flag how to achieve this?

```
if(status==1)
 $status=0;
 else
  $status=1;

UPDATE  `my_table`.`node` SET  `status` =  0 WHERE  ` node`.`nid`    =1059;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Flag 3.x API (PHP)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1748148)

> ```
> mymodule_flag_flag($flag, $content_id, $account, $flagging) {
>   // Do something in response to the flagging.
> }
>
> mymodule_flag_unflag($flag, $content_id, $account, $flagging) {
>   // Do something in response to the unflagging.
> }
> ```

In your case

```
mymodule_flag_flag($flag, $content_id, $account, $flagging) {

  if ($flag->name == 'pick_this_bid'){

     $nid = $content_id;
     db_update('my_table')
       ->expression('status', '0')
       ->condition('nid', $nid)
       ->execute();
  }

}
```